# Bash script fails to connect remote MySQL while it is possible to access it manually

Tags: mysql, bash

I need to write a bash script which would connect to MySQL server on remote host with below command:

```
$MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysql --socket=$MYSQL_UNIX_PORT -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PWD --host $x --connect-timeout=5 -e 'show master status'
```

The script finds 2 database servers (10.5.5.233 and 10.5.5.234) in the config file and it tries to access to each of these hosts. However, the connection fails with "No route to host":

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.5.5.233' (113 "No route to host")
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.5.5.234' (113 "No route to host")
```

On the other hand, the connection to the master database succeeds when I try to connect it manually:

```
$MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysql --socket=$MYSQL_UNIX_PORT -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PWD --host 10.5.5.233 --connect-timeout=5 -e 'show master status'
+------------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+
| File                   | Position | Binlog_Do_DB                                  | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+
| xxx-bin.000006 | 65284117 | xxx,sched,qua,tadb,nodb |                  |
+------------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

I could not find any similar post what could cause this behavior.
Could you please help me understand why bash script fails to connect to MySQL on remote host while the same command succeeds when I run it manually?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the config file for invisible characters (such as carriage return, `${x//$'r'}` would remove all instances of it from `x`) or unicode characters that resemble ASCII ones?

Comment: Also, try putting `set -x` before the relevant section of the script, so bash will print what it thinks the command being executed is, and see if anything looks weird about it.

Comment: @oguzismail, I do not see any related setting in the my.cnf file. Also, it actually fetches the proper IP@ of the remote db servers and tries to connect them. However, it throws "No route to host" error while I am able to access these IP@ manually with the same command.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I added `set -x` to the script, it provided more details in the output (containing proprietary results which I cannot share) but it did not provide any useful info that might give some hints about the reason. The most detailed log is still `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.5.5.233' (113 "No route to host")`

Comment: Well I'm not really convinced, what does `echo "$x" | od -t x1` output?

Comment: @oguzismail, I added `echo $x` and `echo "$x" | od -t x1` commands to the relevant part of the script. Corresponding output snippet: `10.5.5.233
0000000 31 30 2e 35 2e 35 2e 32 33 33 0a
0000013
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.5.5.233' (113 "No route to host")
10.5.5.234
0000000 31 30 2e 35 2e 35 2e 32 33 34 0a
0000013
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.5.5.234' (113 "No route to host")
mysql is not running or this is not the active site!
` do you see any problem in this output?

Comment: @Murat If you copy the exact `mysql` command out of the `set -x` output, paste it into an interactive command line, and press Return, does it work normally?

Comment: Hmm, no. There is nothing wrong there. I couldn't find anything relevant on the Internet either. Following

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yes, when I set the parameter: x to the proper IP@ in the interactive command line and paste the `mysql` command then press Return, it works properly.

Comment: @Murat That's not what I suggested; I suggested copying the full command out of the `set -x` output (except the "+" and space at the front), pasting that into your interactive shell, and running that. Here's the point: there's something different about what you're doing interactively and what the shell script's doing, and it's something you haven't mentioned. Something you don't think is significant. One possibility is the command that's being executed, so running the exact -- and I mean *character-by-character-exactly-identical* -- command interactively tests that as a possible difference.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Well, let me give the details of my script: I have a data collector script (bash - connecting to mysql and fetches data) and a wrapper script which is triggering this data collector. The wrapper script and data collector stored in server A. Wrapper script uploads the data collector to server B and triggers it on server B. Then, data collector script tries to connect to mysql on server C. I got your point now about `set -x` and I confirm that when I copy and paste the exact command (in server B cli) seen in the output log (set -x output), it works fine.

Comment: @Murat Is it possible the command is running on server A rather than B? Anyway, what I'd do to troubleshoot this is try to simplify the situation down to isolate what's causing the problem. So, try skipping the wrapper, putting the script directly on server B, and seeing if it still fails the same way. If it does, then start simplifying the script a bit at a time. See if you can trim it down to just that one command. Probably at some point, it'll start working, so you'll know whatever you just removed was part of the problem (so put it back and try removing something else).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, when I put data collector script to server B and execute it directly there, it runs properly. I will try with trimmed version of the script as you recommended. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @Murat Remember, the trick is to simplify/trim *while keeping the problem*, in order to isolate it. If the script works when run directly on server B, trimming from there won't be informative. Since the A -> B link seems to be important, I'd switch to looking at that. Is it possible the command isn't being executed on B as expected, but maybe still on A, or possibly even somewhere else? What if you run the whole thing normally (wrapper on A triggering the data collector, etc) with just one change: replace the `mysql` command with `hostname`, and see what it prints?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I replaced the `mysql ...` command with `hostname` and I can verify that it prints the hostname of server B.

Comment: @Murat Weird. In that case, I guess the simplify/trim approach is probably the best way to narrow down the cause. You'll apparently need to keep the "wrapper on A triggers collector on B" structure, but trim both down as much as possible while keeping the problem. Whenever you remove something and it starts working, that tells you the thing you just removed is part of the problem.

Comment: Oh, one other test occurs to me: try replacing the `mysql` command with `ping -c2 10.5.5.233`, and see if that also gets a "no route to host" error.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, `ping -c2 10.5.5.233` also worked fine. Well, I think I will need to design my use-case from scratch. It seems I will not be able to get over the issue. Thanks a lot for all your advises and help.